# VGA splitter vs DisplayPort to VGA converter image quality comparison

Tags: display, gpu, conversion, vga, displayport

I have an [ATI Radeon™ HD 5770](https://web.archive.org/web/20160222141156/https://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/5000/5770#) GPU (2 DVI-I ports, 1 HDMI port and 1 DisplayPort) and I have an [HP Compaq LE1711 17-inch LCD Monitor](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01925869/) (1 VGA port).

I'm trying to find the best way to achieve the highest image quality I can get given that the 2 DVI-I ports are already being used by 2 other monitors using 2 DVI-I to VGA adapters. As such I have 2 options so far with the final goal being running 3 monitors at once.

I believe I have the following options:

1. Unplug one of the monitors from the DVI-I port and use a VGA splitter, which I already have. I have tried this already, but the image quality isn't that great. All 3 monitors run at once.
2. Buy a DisplayPort to VGA converter.

I tested an HDMI to VGA converter, but the quality loss was worse than it was for the VGA splitter. Even if that worked, it seems I can't get to work 3 monitors at once by using this configuration, that's why I read on the internet that I have to go for a DisplayPort to VGA converter.

Can anyone tell me if the DisplayPort to VGA converter would yield a better image than the VGA splitter assuming both of them are top of the line products?

Comment: The quality of the converter's circuitry is what matters, not the connection.

Comment: That, and the goal. @rd51: Good convertors are not cheap and a 5770 is OLD. Even in these crypto cursed times it might be cheaper to add a second graphics card.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply!
@ChanganAuto Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply!
@Hennes Thank you! I read online that having 2 GPUs of different brands, as it's my case, would produce system instability. As such, I went with buying a DisplayPort to VGA converter, and I'm pretty happy about the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI and DisplayPort are both digital outputs. They either produce perfect quality image, or they don't work at all. Switching between them doesn't affect quality.

VGA is analog, so cable and connection can affect image quality. The adapter is also a factor.

A good adapter should produce results no worse than a direct DVI-I connection. Check your adapter and analog cables, if any.